# Are original documents for the short-term study visa are also not required anymore?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, russian-citizens

I got back from UK visa center in Moscow after applying for a Standard Visitor visa. They did not accept any of my originals documents, only copies. They scanned my copies and gave them back to me. I asked two workers there:

> -- Don't you accept any of originals **for all kinds of visas?**
>
> -- **No, we do not**

Now I am asking the community here:

**Originals documents for Short-term study visa are also not required anymore?**

Please be aware that [Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) the following is written:

> All documents must be originals and not photocopies.

But actually, for Standard Visitor Visa it is not true anymore.

Comment: Not sure where the question is in all of this. It seems to have a question with an answer as if it is some kind of an announcement of a change in the UK visa rules rather than an actual question.

Comment: @RichardChambers no, I wish to know if there is the same changes for short-term visitor visa as for standard visitor visa.

Comment: There is no UK visa called "short-term visitor visa."  The visa issued by the UK to most short-term visitors is called "standard visitor visa."

Comment: @phoog While the op uses the incorrect term in a comment, I believe the question is worded correctly.

Comment: @phoog no, man, there is exactly short-term study visa.  Please read here https://www.gov.uk/study-visit-visa

Comment: I was responding to your comment: "I wish to know if there is the same changes for short-term visitor visa as for standard visitor visa."  Perhaps you meant to type "...for short-term study visa as for standard visitor visa."

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you were told what you were. All online documentation, including the [Short Term Study VISA application page on the UK Government site](https://www.gov.uk/study-visit-visa/documents-you-must-provide) says you need original documentation only.

In your case, were I you (if you can afford it), I would take the originals, certified copies, and regular copies of all of your documentation. That way, no matter what they ask for, you've covered all of your bases, so to speak.

Comment: I was not only told, I was not allowed to come in apply room before I have a copies, because they accept only originals. So I made a copies and only after that I was allowed to come through turnstile for applying. The officer then did not take my originals

Comment: You were asked to bring in certified copies? Or you were asked to make copies of your originals to be turned in (perhaps their copier was broken?) or did they ask you to bring in Certified Copies? In any event, there is no way for any of us to give you a better answer, as far as I could find, as the UK Government's own web site stipulates only originals.

Comment: No, I was not, and I was not asked to make copies of my originals to be turned in my application. They did not ask to bring certified copies. They kindly ask me to make copies by using copier in the same room as we were. They asked me to do so because "Embassy is not accepting originals anymore". I left this question because hope to find more people experienced the same new rules.

Comment: in web version reply does not work. Please read my comment above that one

Answer (score 1):

It was a case for the Moscow center. They took your copies because you have original documents, thus in this way, they confirm that you have in fact original documents. 
For further work the Migration only deals with copies. It is understandable for them that you have original docs.

If you did not bring the original docs, they could reject taking only copies. But in fact, and in my case they often accept copies without original docs, it is probably depends on the officer.